# |Discord Bot Error: Cannot find module './commands/ban.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const  Discord  = require('discord.js')
const { error } = require('console');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const PREFIX = "zm.";


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}



client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);




client.on('ready', () =>{ 
    console.log('ZeKuS Modification bot is now online!');
    client.user.setActivity('ZeKuS Modification | ZM', {type: 'PLAYING'}).catch(console.error)});







    

    client.on('message', message =>{
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
        
        const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/\s+/);
        const cmd = args.shift();
        const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of commandFiles){
            const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }
        if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

        try{
            client.commands.get(cmd).execute(message, args);
        } catch (error){
            console.error(error);
            message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
        }
    })






  

 //verify 





//ban

 





client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log(member.user.tag);
});
```

Error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './commands/ban.js'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\uporabnik\Documents\GitHub\zm-bot\src\bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\uporabnik\Documents\GitHub\zm-bot\src\bot.js:13:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'c:\\Users\\uporabnik\\Documents\\GitHub\\zm-bot\\src\\bot.js' ]
}
```

My folderss:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Ora.png)

Error: Cannot find module './commands/ban.js'
Require stack:

- c:\Users\uporabnik\Documents\GitHub\zm-bot\src\bot.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)

Basicly it trows the error and Im not sure how to fix it, please help since Im just stuck at the mmoment

Comment: Are all your existing files displayed in `commandFiles `? If not, try searching for ´fs.readdirSync(`../commands/`) [...]´

Comment: It seems you're trying to access `/commands/ban.js` from `/src/bot.js`. It's in a different directory, so you need to go out first. You either need to move the `commands` folder inside `src` (preferred), or update your paths from `./commands/` to `../commands/`. See the double dots.

Answer (score 1):

Your folder structure looks like this:

```
ZM-Bot/
      |
      Commands/
      |  |
      |  ban.js
      |
      src/
         |
         app.js
```

If you want to require `ban.js` from `app.js`, you need to navigate out of `src/` first. 
So the path is `../commands/ban.js`.

```js
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`../commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```